# Implementing a customDao in JPA Spring JPARepository error at running

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement a daoImpl in a Spring JPA applicacion.

I have this classes.

Dao

```
package com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.oxygen.backendoxygen.model.Noticia;

@Repository
public interface NoticiaDao extends JpaRepository<Noticia, Long>, NoticiaDaoCustom {

}
```

Custom Dao:

```
package com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.oxygen.backendoxygen.model.Noticia;

public interface NoticiaDaoCustom {

    List<Noticia> getUltimasNoticias();

}
```

And the impl of the custom Dao:

```
package com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDao;
import com.oxygen.backendoxygen.model.Noticia;


public abstract class NoticiaDaoCustomImpl implements NoticiaDao {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Noticia> getUltimasNoticias () {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT em.* FROM spring_data_jpa_example.employee as em " +
                "WHERE em.firstname LIKE ?", Noticia.class);
        query.setParameter(1, "parametro");

        return query.getResultList();
        
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
package com.oxygen.backendoxygen.controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDao;
import com.oxygen.backendoxygen.model.Noticia;

@RestController @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class NoticiaController {
    
    @Autowired
    NoticiaDao noticiaDao;
    
    @GetMapping("/noticias")
    public List<Noticia> getAllNoticias() {
        
        return noticiaDao.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/noticias/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Noticia> getNoticiabyId (@PathVariable(value = "id") Long idNoticia) {
        
        Noticia noticia = noticiaDao.getById(idNoticia);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(noticia);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/createNoticia")
    public Noticia createNoticia(@Valid @RequestBody Noticia noticia) {
        return noticiaDao.save(noticia);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/updateNoticia/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Noticia> updateNoticia(@PathVariable(value="id") Long idNoticia,
            @Valid @RequestBody Noticia detallesNoticia) {
        
        Noticia noticia = noticiaDao.getById(idNoticia);
        noticia.setAutor(detallesNoticia.getAutor());
        noticia.setContenido(detallesNoticia.getContenido());
        noticia.setCategorias(detallesNoticia.getCategorias());
        noticia.setFx_edicion_fx(detallesNoticia.getFx_edicion_fx());
        noticia.setFx_publicacion_fx(detallesNoticia.getFx_publicacion_fx());
        noticia.setImagen_destacada(detallesNoticia.getImagen_destacada());
        noticia.setSubtitulo(detallesNoticia.getSubtitulo());
        noticia.setTitulo(detallesNoticia.getTitulo());
        
        final Noticia noticiaActualizado = noticiaDao.save(noticia);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(noticiaActualizado);
        
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("borrarNoticia/{id}")
    public Map<String,Boolean> deleteNoticia(@PathVariable(value="id") Long idNoticia) {
        
        Noticia noticia = noticiaDao.getById(idNoticia);
        noticiaDao.delete(noticia);
        
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("borrado", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }

}
```

When i try to run the application I have the next errors:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-10-14 11:39:03.306 ERROR 11992 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'noticiaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'noticiaDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'noticiaDao' defined in com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! No property getUltimasNoticias found for type Noticia!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! No property getUltimasNoticias found for type Noticia!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.oxygen.backendoxygen.BackendOxygenApplication.main(BackendOxygenApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'noticiaDao' defined in com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! No property getUltimasNoticias found for type Noticia!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! No property getUltimasNoticias found for type Noticia!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! No property getUltimasNoticias found for type Noticia!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! No property getUltimasNoticias found for type Noticia!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.oxygen.backendoxygen.dao.NoticiaDaoCustom.getUltimasNoticias()! No property getUltimasNoticias found for type Noticia!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getUltimasNoticias found for type Noticia!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

What is wrong here. I have readed Spring docs and i dont find how to use JPA and custom methods for query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide your `Controller` class, as I can see the exception says something about `noticiaController`.

Comment: @Aris done ty .

Comment: As I can see, `spring` will never be able to manage your `NoticiaDaoCustomImpl` because it is not a manageable bean. I believe that `@Componenet` will solve your issue, not sure though. `@Component` is an annotation that allows Spring to automatically detect our custom beans.

Comment: So i should add @Component to Impl class??

Comment: Yeap try it, to indicate to the `Spring ApplicationContext` that this is a `bean`

Comment: I am learning about Spring and i dont know how to do it. Do you have any example of what you are saying me to do?? ty

Comment: As I can see your `NoticiaDaoCustomImpl` class is abstract. So `Spring` will never be able to create an instance of that class. Remove `abstract` and add `@Component` on top of that class.

Comment: That was the key!! It worked ty so much!! You can add as answer so i can valorate your help!!

Comment: No worries, I created an answer so we can help others with the same issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NoticiaDaoCustomImpl` class is `abstract`, so Spring will never be able to create an instance of that class. Remove abstract and add `@Component` on top of that class.

> `@Component` is an annotation that allows Spring to automatically detect custom beans.

Check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-annotation) from more information about `@Component`

And this is the definition for `abstract` class:

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

Read more about `abstract` classes [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in spring boot, there is no dao concept, instead it is a repository concept, for example ExampleRepository (which is the class that extends JpaRepository or crudRepository ) will correspond to Example (Entity)

for your purposes you can convert Example to whatever you want.

i am java develop on 1 year, so the answer may be not true.

update:

Controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class ExampleControler {
    private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    public ExampleControler(ExampleRepository exampleRepository) {
        this.exampleRepository = exampleRepository;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/dd")
    public void deleteAll() {
        exampleRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "example")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Example {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "example1")
    private Integer example1;

    @Column(name = "example2")
    private Integer example2;
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Integer> {
}
```

that is the basic architecture of spring boot project, you probably know. in application.properties you can add code blow to check query

```
JpaRepository<Example, Integer>
```

parameter is Entity, from this Entity, you can convert Class you want

Comment: I think is just naming, because its working well without the Impl. Ty for your answer.

Comment: here, parameter in JpaRepository<Noticia, Long>, you should replace Noticia with what you consider to be the Entity that I mentioned above.
`
@Repository
public interface NoticiaDao extends JpaRepository<Noticia, Long>, NoticiaDaoCustom {

}
`

Comment: Mmmm I dont understand what you mean. Can you use a code examples?? ty very much.

Comment: @Angel, i edit my Answer, Hope it helps you.